# Revolution slider not loading images on first time

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, revolution-slider

I have high definition images on my site. Everything was working fine, but since last update, revolution slider is not showing up images randomly. Have a look at attached image.

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2511568/e6294730098ec75672f7c13f7252c397

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have u checked the img urls are working fine or not ? may be a read permission issue !

Comment: Could you post the actual website URL?

Comment: @Alice its not read permission issue. Same image is loaded when I refresh.

Comment: @RodneyZanoria No, I am afraid.

Comment: Is there any space available in any folder name from where images are getting loaded?
It was in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find that your image slider is loaded but the slides are not showing. Sometimes the images are not properly uploaded or your image slider code files may be causing a code conflict.

If your slider plugin isn’t updated or doesn’t match to your WordPress version, it can also cause a problem with the images. Try simply updating your WordPress and all plugins to the latest versions. It may resolve this issue.

If your images still aren’t appearing, it could be a caching issue. See this guide on how to clear your cache in WordPress to see if that solves the problem.